# I'm confused by the waypoint order I'm getting using the Direction API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm quite confused by the waypoint order I'm getting by sending the request..

At First I sent..

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New Delhi&destination=Chennai&waypoints=optimize:true|Agra|Bhopal|Nagpur|Vijaywada&key="YOUR API KEY"

and got Waypoint_order as :
"waypoint_order": [
                0,
                1,
                2,
                3
            ]

The above one is good for me..
But,
Then, I mixed up the waypoints and sent another request as:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New Delhi&destination=Chennai&waypoints=optimize:true|Vijaywada|Agra|Bhopal|Nagpur&key="Your API KEY"

and got Waypoint Order as :
"waypoint_order": [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                0
            ]

Can, Somebody help me with this..

Comment: And what's wrong with it? The order is exactly the same in both your examples.

Comment: I was confused with the way point order... Now it's solved.. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your first example:**

You pass: `Agra|Bhopal|Nagpur|Vijaywada`

- 0 - Agra
- 1 - Bhopal
- 2 - Nagpur
- 3 - Vijaywada

You receive waypoint_order `0,1,2,3` in other words **Agra > Bhopal > Nagpur > Vijaywada**

**In your second example:**

You pass: `Vijaywada|Agra|Bhopal|Nagpur`

- 0 - Vijaywada
- 1 - Agra
- 2 - Bhopal
- 3 - Nagpur

You receive waypoint_order `1,2,3,0` in other words **Agra > Bhopal > Nagpur > Vijaywada**

In both cases, the API returned the same waypoints order.